# log4net FileAppender System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, log4net

I'm using log4net in a small console application that is started by another application in a sort of shell way. What I'm finding is that every once and a while the app crashes when shutting down and from looking at the stack trace it seems like log4net is waiting for a thread lock to be lifted, but when it does the manual reset event is already disposed. I have tried subscribing to the ILog.Logger.Repository.ShutdownEvent to delay the closing of the app until log4net has cleaned up it's resources but I can still reproduce the error with those checks in place. Any ideas?

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ObjectDisposedException
Stack: at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, UInt32, Boolean, Boolean)
at System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, Int64, Boolean, Boolean)
at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32, Boolean)
at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne()
at log4net.Appender.FileAppender+InterProcessLock.AcquireLock()
at log4net.Appender.FileAppender+LockingStream.AcquireLock()
at log4net.Appender.FileAppender.WriteFooter()
at log4net.Appender.TextWriterAppender.WriteFooterAndCloseWriter()
at log4net.Appender.FileAppender.Reset()
at log4net.Appender.TextWriterAppender.OnClose()
at log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.Close()
at log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.Finalize()
```

Comment: Sounds to me like a log4net bug.  What version are you using?  You could try posting details of the problem to the log4net user mailing list: log4net-user@logging.apache.org

Comment: Using version 1.2.13.0, I'll submit it as you suggested.

Comment: Weird I got this response when submitting. 

'This log4net list is closed. See http://logging.apache.org/log4net/support.html for details of the new
mailing lists.', and the supplied link doesn't go anywhere

Comment: Use this url to subscribe to the mailing list: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/mail-lists.html

Comment: Definitely looks like a bug in the InterProcessLock locking model.  Pending a fix, could you use a different locking model such as MinimalLock?  Or even ExclusiveLock, which will give you better performance, but require you to use different files for each process.